# Is it possible to mirror a Bitbucket repository hosted in a private domain in Google Cloud Source Repositories?

Tags: google-cloud-source-repos

Would like to know if mirroring can be setup between a BitBucket server hosted in a company domain with Google Cloud Source repositories?

Comment: Have you checked [this](https://cloud.google.com/source-repositories/docs/mirroring-a-bitbucket-repository)?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're talking about [BitBucket Self-Hosted Server](https://www.atlassian.com/software/bitbucket/enterprise/data-center). Currently there's no way to mirror BitBucket Server from Cloud Source Repository (CSR) side, only the cloud Bitbucket.

However you can try to set up a manual mirrorring from BitBucket side. I've never tested this configuration, but [here](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Bitbucket-questions/Sync-up-Bitbucket-with-Git-Hub/qaq-p/712834) you will find instructions on how to do it with GitHub using remotes. You can try it using CSR instead. [Here](https://cloud.google.com/source-repositories/docs/adding-repositories-as-remotes) are the instructions on how to add CSR as remote.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Yes, I was referring to self-hosted Bitbucket server. I will try the option which you have provided.